# InitCommonControlsEx() function not recognised by compiler

Tags: c++, function, winapi, header, controls

I am trying to call InitCommonControlsEx() in the main entry of a window program, and although I included the header  and linked to the ComCtl32.Lib, for some reason the compiler underlines that function as undefined.  Following is the code...

```
#include <CommCtrl.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX initControls;
initControls.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
initControls.dwICC = ICC_BAR_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&initControls);
}
```

I know that the inclusion of the  is doing something, because if I delete the inclusion of that header, then the compiler doesn't recognise the class INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX.

I am really confused.  I went into the CommCtrl.h file and found that many sections were underlined in red giving warnings by the compiler, including any reference to WINAPI.  Could it be that I have a broken header?  I know the functions declaration is in there, it's in the following picture...

[image]

I've been googling for hours and can't figure it out.  There's not a DLL file I also need, is there?  As I said I've already linked the ComCtl32.Lib, sometimes referred to as comctl32.lib (I don't think the capitals matter).  Furthermore, on my computer I have 4 instances of this ComCtl32.Lib, two are for 64bit and two are for x86.  But, my feeling is that the problem is it just can't find declaration of that function from that header.  Thank you.

Edit:  Thanks to Harry Johnson I fixed the problem.  I had no idea that including standard header files requires that you include other header files before them.  In this case the compiler didn't recognise anything because windows.h wasn't included BEFORE CommCtrl.h.  An obvious mistake for anyone who knows what they're doing.  You can delete this question entirely.  I expected that when including a header that windows provides that all relevant dependencies are included in that header.

Comment: Please print the error message.

Comment: Is that the *complete* source code?  Or have you left out an `#include <windows.h>` at the top?

Comment: If I comment out the #include <CommCtrl.h> all the errors go away.  When I leave it in I get:

Error (active)  variable "HRESULT" is not a type name mySDK c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\shellapi.h 1606

Error (active)  variable "BOOL" is not a type name mySDK c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\CommCtrl.h 5867

Something is really wrong here.

Comment: Your description of the problem is confusing; it shouldn't build without the `#include` since WINAPI, HINSTANCE, and LPSTR should all be undefined.  But I suspect the problem is that you haven't included `windows.h`.  You must do so before including `commctrl.h`.

Comment: That's it.  I did include <windows.h>, but in the header.  I included <windows.h> in main.h, thinking that because main.h is included is main.cpp, in turn main.cpp will include <windows.h>.  Why doesn't it work like this?  Also if I include windows.h after CommCtrl.h it doesn't work.  Thanks so much for your help.  But why must it be included again?  Does that mean if windows.h is included in my main.h I should include windows.h again in my cpp?  That would be including it twice, but I do have #pragma once, so, is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: I understand now.  And I don't have to include it twice, as long as I include CommCtrl.h AFTER including main.h (which includes windows.h), it's fine.  It's making sense now.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you see LNK2019 in Visual Studio 2022, add the #pragma line.

```
#include <CommCtrl.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "comctl32.lib" )

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX initControls;
    initControls.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    initControls.dwICC = ICC_BAR_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&initControls);
}
```

Comment: I can't see how adding the `#pragma comment(...` line will help resolve a **compiler** message that a function is undefined. That line sends data to the *linker*.